# how to git push code to remote repository when repository changes are not in your local machine

Tags: git, github

i have had trouble pushing my code to remote repository on github. I think the problem has started because i updated my code directly on github.
here is the error I am getting

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:Deniskiplangat/crud-application.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried to run `git push`I got the changes that I had made online reflected in my current project but still got a few error or hint messages that I dont get.

```
hint: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
hint: discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
hint: commands sometime before your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: cannot run emacs: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'emacs'
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
```

finally i tried pushing to the repository and got the following messages

```
! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:Deniskiplangat/crud-application.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not even doing what the hints tell you to do.

> You may want to first integrate the remote changes (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

So you would want to say `git pull`. Notice the dots; you need to specify here what you want pulled and from where. For example you might say `git pull origin main`.

> Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: cannot run emacs: No such file or directory. Error: unable to start editor 'emacs'. Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.

Your `git pull` performed a merge. A merge makes a commit. The commit needs a commit message. You need to provide it. But your configuration is broken; it says that `emacs` is your editor but you don't have `emacs`. So you would want to say `git commit -m 'my message'` to complete the merge without any editor (and you can straighten out the editor situation later).

> finally i tried pushing

But you never finished pulling (as I explained in the previous paragraph), so you get exactly the same result as when you pushed the first time.

Now, in actual fact, I wouldn't do any of that. This is how I would handle your situation (if you had not made the mistake of leaving yourself in an incoherent state with a half-formed merge commit):

```
git switch main
git fetch origin main
git rebase origin/main
git push origin main
```

Comment: And please read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/ which has a section about _exactly_ the problem you are having.